# .gitconfig error

Tags: git, version-control, labview, git-config

I edited my .gitconfig file to add support for LabView and it appears that I did something that Git doesn't exactly like. The problem is it (Git) doesn't tell me what it doesn't like. What did I do wrong?

The error message doesn't help much either:
"fatal: bad config file line 13 in c:/Users/Tanner/.gitconfig"

```
[gui]
    recentrepo = C:/Users/Tanner/Desktop/FIRST 2010 Beta/Java/LoganRover

[user]
    name = Tanner Smith
    email = tanner@notimportant.net

[merge "labview"]
    name = LabView 3-Way Merge
    driver =  “C:\Program Files\National Instruments\Shared\LabVIEW Merge\LVMerge.exe” “C:\Program Files\National Instruments\LabVIEW 8.6\LabVIEW.exe” %O %B %A %A
    recursive = binary
```

And I'm not seeing a line 13, but usually that would mean something is wrong at the end? I don't know, Git is new to me.

Comment: @Tanner: to add to my own answer, did you try straight double-quotes (`"`) instead of smart ones (`“` and `”`)? That should allow sh to execute on a path like `"C:\Program Files\..."` instead of the non existent `C:\Program `.

Answer (score 4):

Hmm. You seem to have smart quotes (`“` and `”`) on the `driver` line instead of straight quotes (`"`). That might cause some problems. Another thing to check is to see if there is a mix of LF and CRLF line endings; that might make the line count be different than what it looks like. Try looking at your file in a hex editor, or an editor that will display all whitespace characters, to see if you have a mix of line endings.

Answer (score 4):

A/ I confirm the problematic line is

```
    driver =  “C:\Program Files\National Instruments\Shared\LabVIEW Merge\LVMerge.exe” “C:\Program Files\National Instruments\LabVIEW 8.6\LabVIEW.exe” %O %B %A %A
```

B/ The quotes are not the issue (`“` or `"`), although the resulting command will not work unless you are using `"` only. But at least `“` does not trigger the "invalid .gitconfig" error message.

C/ The problem is the `\` which have to be escaped themselves.

```
    driver =  “C:\\Program Files\\National Instruments\\Shared\\LabVIEW Merge\\LVMerge.exe” “C:\\Program Files\\National Instruments\\LabVIEW 8.6\\LabVIEW.exe” %O %B %A %A
```

will work.

Comment: That fixed the config problem, though when it needs to merge it complains:
sh: C:Program: command not found
error: cannot run sh: No such file or directory
fatal: Failed to execute internal merge

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple things that may be a problem.  One of which is you are using curly quotes on line 10, and no quotes on line 2.

What editor did you edit this with?  Please use a plain text editor like notepad or vim.

Lastly: use **git-config** to edit this file, rather than by hand.  See the following link:

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

Comment: This is all good advice too, though sometimes it is easier to edit this in a text editor than through `git-config`.

Answer (score 0):

Other possible problems are the file paths with spaces in them. I would remove the spaces and replace them with underscores or dashes.

Answer (score 0):

I see forward slashes (/) on the second line and backward (\) on the LabVIEW Merge line.
Maybe they are the culprit?

Ton